# Mejor método para chequeo de notificaciones en tiempo real

Tags: android, ionic2

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación móvil en Ionic (aunque dudo que ese dato sea importante), en ella, cuando pulso determinado botón debo avisarle a otro usuario que eso ocurrió. Para implementar esto lo único que se me ocurren es poner a la aplicación del receptor en segundo plano a chequear contra un servidor cada X intervalo de tiempo. El tema es que necesito que la recepción sea **instantánea** o por lo menos con el menor intervalo de tiempo posible al estilo de aplicaciones como Telegram o WhatsApp.

No se si es una buena práctica poner a chequear en segundo plano a cada segundo.

Leí sobre observers en tiempo real que el servidor avisa de forma automática pero no tengo idea siquiera de que nombre reciben o cuál es el nombre de la solucion planteada. Me interesa que la solución además de ser **factible** en términos de respuesta y consumo de recursos, sea de **buena práctica**.

¿Está bien la solución de chequeo constante o hay un método mejor que desconozco?

Comment: Bueno amigo te propongo chequees `firebase` es una base de datos en tiempo real que maneja Notificaciones y muchas cosas mas aparte de que es gratuita para proyectos beta te dejo el link saludos [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) Aparte tiene muchas APIs para app móviles espero te ayude saludos

Comment: Hola Luis! Gracias por responder y disculpame la tardanza de mi respuesta. Estuve viendo Firebase, pero Ionic dejó de dar soporte gratuito y a partir de Enero del 2018 hay que empezar a pagar. Me parece que voy a utilizar WebSockets con Ratchet en PHP y poner observers en Angular. En cuanto lo implemente pondré una respuesta para quien le sirva. Saludos y gracias nuevamente!